# Import Deep Learning Models into Django

Tags: python, django, deep-learning

**Background**

I was building a demo search engine and met a problem of loading my DL models into `django`. My code is basically structured like this:

```
models/
    DPR.py       # save model defination
utils/
    manager.py   # save model hyperparameter settings
backend/
    SearchApp/
        app.py   # where I want to load my model
        view.py  # where I want to use my model
```

To clarify, my model should be initialized this way:

```
from utils.manager import Manager
from models.DPR import DPR

manager = Manager()
model = DPR(manager)
```

**Problems**

1. I want to load the model **once** after the django app run.
2. I failed to load the model in `backend/SearchEngine/app.py` as suggested in [here](https://medium.com/saarthi-ai/deploying-a-machine-learning-model-using-django-part-1-6c7de05c8d7) because of `ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`.

So any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you do the import you need in your `app.py`? If it's a problem related to circular imports: note that you can put an `import` statement inside a function; it doesn't have to be at the top of the file. Doing the import inside the function that needs it is a good quick-and-dirty fix for circular dependencies.

Comment: Actually I'm indeed importing in `app.py`. I got the `ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package` raised from `from ...utils.manager import Manager`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by

```
class Backbone():
    import sys
    sys.path.append("..")

    from models.DPR import DPR
```

in `backend/SearchEngine/app.py`, after which I can `from .apps import Backbone` to use the model.